# Twillio call disconnect after the user recieves one ring

Tags: xml, laravel-5, twilio

I want to immediately terminate a call as soon as the call is initialized an the user gets one ring

this are my routes

```
Route::any('missedCall','RegistrationController@missedCall');
Route::any('callForMissedCall',function(){
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?   ><Response/>');
    $xml->addChild('Dial timeout="0"');
    $header['Content-Type'] = 'application/xml';
    return Response::make($xml->asXML(), '200', $header);
});
```

and the function that I am calling with the first route

```
    public function missedCall(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        if (isset($data['id'])) {
            Response::json(array("status"=>'failure',"msg"=>'Missing    argument'));
        }
        $regDetails = RegistrationDetails::find($data['id']);

        if (!$regDetails)
            return Response::json(array("status"=>"failure","msg"=>"No     data is present"));
        $phone_no = $regDetails->phone_no;
        $country = $regDetails->country;
        if (!$country)
            return    Response::json(array("status"=>"failure","msg"=>"Country missing"));
        $countryData = Country::where('name',"LIKE",$country)->first();

        $phnCode = $countryData->phonecode;
        $phone = "+".$phnCode.$phone_no;
        $twilio = Twilio::call($phone,     $_ENV['app_url']."/callForMissedCall");
     }
```

The above code only terminates after the user picks the call. Any solution around this.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

We just introduced a new feature called [Call Progress Events](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/05/introducing-call-progress-events-flexibly-track-and-control-your-outbound-calls.html) which gives you more granular notifications as a call progresses.  I'm not sure we can let you know that a call made exactly one ring, but I know we can tell you that it is "ringing" vs "answered".

If you detect "ringing" you could subsequently terminate the call.

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Following this link from twillio  https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial
I was able to implement the calling.. It is not quite possible to terminate the call but one can follow my code to see how i was able to achieve this

```
    public function missedCall($id)
{
    if (isset($id)) {
        Response::json(array("status"=>'failure',"msg"=>'Missing argument'));
    }
    $regDetails = RegistrationDetails::find($id);

    if (!$regDetails)
        return Response::json(array("status"=>"failure","msg"=>"No data is present"));
    $phone_no = $regDetails->phone_no;
    $country = $regDetails->country;
    if (!$country)
        return Response::json(array("status"=>"failure","msg"=>"Country missing"));
    $countryData = Country::where('name',"LIKE",$country)->first();

    $phnCode = $countryData->phonecode;
    $phone = "+".$phnCode.$phone_no;
    $twilio = Twilio::call($phone, $_ENV['app_url']."/callForMissedCall");
}
```

on the xml part of it

```
   Route::any('callForMissedCall',function(){
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response/>');
$xml->addChild('Dial');
$header['Content-Type'] = 'application/xml';
return Response::make($xml->asXML(), '200', $header);
```

});